# jquery thumbnail gallery - hover/fade

Tags: jquery, hover, fade, rollover

I have been struggling to get an answer to this...
I have a series of thumbnails, and when I roll over them I would like the main image (in a separate div) to change to that of the thumbnail that is rolled on.
I am new to programming however I am happy with the basic functionality I get with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var originalimg = $('.mainImage').attr('src');
    $(".subImage").hover(function() {
        var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.mainImage').attr('src', currentimg);
    }, function() {
        $('.mainImage').attr('src', originalimg);
    });
});​
```

What I would ideally like is to add some fade in/out effect.
I am sure there is a much better way of achieving this, but if someone could just change my code above to include some fade, I would really appreciate it. thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should prevent any flicker or queue build up:

```
var originalimg = $('.mainImage').attr('src');
$(".subImage").hover(function() {
    var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.mainImage').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.mainImage').attr('src', currentimg).fadeIn();
    });
}, function() {
    $('.mainImage').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.mainImage').attr('src', originalimg).fadeIn();
    })
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FDpea/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

With chaining, use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`

```
var originalimg = $('.mainImage').attr('src');
$(".subImage").hover(function() {
    var currentimg = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.mainImage')
        .stop()
        .fadeOut()
        .attr('src', currentimg)
        .fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('.mainImage')
        .stop()
        .fadeOut()
        .attr('src', originalimg)
        .fadeIn();
});​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FDpea/1)

Comment: Might want to add some .stop()s in there to stop the queue build up.